# Show that $1/|x|$ is not Lipschitz continuous on $|x|<1$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus

$x$ is a $3$d vector. This is what I have so far, don't know if it is enough to prove , that $f(x) = 1/|x|$ is not Lipschitz-continuous on $|x|<1$:
First we have to show, that for all $L>0$ there exist $x,y$ with $|x|<1$, $|y|<1$ such that $|f(x) - f(y)| > L \cdot |x-y|$.
Let $0<a<1/(|x|^2\cdot L )$ and $y=a\cdot x$ and we choose $x$ such that $|x|>1/L$ (now it is unclear here why $|x|<1$.) Then we have:
$|y| = a \cdot |x| < |x|/(|x|^2\cdot L) = 1/(|x|\cdot L) < 1$ and in particular $1/(|x|\cdot|y|) > L$. Then we have:

$|f(x)-f(y)| = |1/|x|-1/|y|| = ||x|-|y||/(|x|\cdot|y|) = |x-y|/(|x|\cdot|y|) > L |x-y|$.

Now I am sure I am missing some detail to complete the exercise, but don't know where to look at.

Comment: Sure you got the statement of the problem right? Doesn't make much sense, because $1/||x|$ is not even _defined_ for $|x|<1$...

Comment: The problem is to find out if $f(x) = 1/|x|$ is Lipschitz continuous on ${x: |x| < 1}$, $f:R^3->R$ and if so to give the Lipschitz constant.

Comment: @stackExchangeUser: I think David's point is that $1/0$ is undefined.

Comment: Yes, I know... But that's how it is written in the book. I guess it should be $0<|x|<1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your life easier by choosing simple $x$ and $y$, say $x:=(a,0,0)$ and $y:=(b,0,0)$, with both $a$ and $b$ between $0$ and $1$. Then
$$
\left|f(x)-f(y)\right|=\left|\frac1a-\frac1b\right|={\left|b-a\right|\over ab}>\frac1a\left|b-a\right|=\frac1a\left|x-y\right|,\tag1 $$
and with suitable choice of $a$ you can make the RHS of (1) as large as you want.

Comment: A suitable choice would be $a > 1/L$ for some $L> 0$, right?

Comment: Given $L$, take $a<1/L$ -- we want $a$ to be small!

Comment: Ok, yes, that's what I actually meant. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right way. You got
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| = |x-y|/(|x|\cdot|y|) 
$$
and $1/(|x|\cdot|y|)  $ is by sure unbounded  for $ x,y\in D:=\{z\in\mathbb R^n\setminus(0): |z|\leq 1\}$. So
$$
|f(x)-f(y)| \leq L|x-y|\quad \forall x,y\in D
$$
cannot hold for any positive $L$.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $f(x)= \frac{1}{\Vert x \Vert}$ is lipschitz for $0< \Vert x \Vert <1$. Then there exists $L>0$ such that

$$ L \Vert x - y \Vert \geq \vert f(x) - f(y) \vert = \frac{\vert \  \Vert x \Vert - \Vert y \Vert \ \vert}{\Vert x \Vert \cdot \Vert y \Vert}.$$

Not choose $2y=x$, then you get

$$ L \Vert x \Vert \geq \frac{\frac{1}{2}\Vert x \Vert}{\frac{1}{2} \Vert x \Vert^2} = \frac{1}{ \Vert x \Vert}$$

and therefore

$$ L \geq \frac{1}{\Vert x \Vert^2}.$$

This gives you a contradiction.

Comment: I think you mean $y = 2x$. How do you know that $ 0 < |y| < 1$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out that my calculation is wrong. I meant $2y=x$ (precisely to avoid the issue that you wrote). I'll correct my computations.